# feeding data into an LSTM - Tensorflow RNN PTB tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to feed data into an LSTM.  I am reviewing the code from [Tensorflow's RNN tutorial here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent).

The segment of code of interest is from the `reader.py` file of the tutorial, in particular the `ptb_producer` function, which ouputs the `X` and `Y` that is used by the LSTM.

`raw_data` is a list of indexes of words from the `ptb.train.txt` file. The length of `raw_data` is 929,589. `batch_size` is 20, `num_steps` is 35. Both `batch_size` and `num_steps` are based on the `LARGEconfig` which feeds the data to an LSTM.

I have walked through the code (and added comments for what I've printed) and I understand it up till `tf.strided_slice`.  From the reshape, we have a matrix of indexes of shape `(20, 46497)`.

Strided slice in the first iteration of `i`, tries to take data from `[0, i * num_steps + 1]` which is `[0,1*35+1]` till `[batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps + 1]` which is `[20, (1+1)*35+1]`.

Two questions:

1. where in the matrix is `[0,1*35+1]` and `[20, (1+1)*35+1]`?  What spots in the `(20, 46497)` the begin and end in strided_slice is trying to access?
2. It seems like EVERY iteration of `i`, will take in data from 0?  the very start of the data matrix `(20, 46497)`?

I guess what I am not understanding is how you would feed data into an LSTM, given the batch size and the `num_steps` (sequence length).

I have read [colahs blog on LSTM](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) and [Karpathy's blog on RNN](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) which helps greatly in the understanding of LSTMs, but don't seem to address the exact mechanics of getting data into an LSTM. (maybe I missed something?)

```py
def ptb_producer(raw_data, batch_size, num_steps, name=None):
  """Iterate on the raw PTB data.
  This chunks up raw_data into batches of examples and returns Tensors that
  are drawn from these batches.
  Args:
    raw_data: one of the raw data outputs from ptb_raw_data.
    batch_size: int, the batch size.
    num_steps: int, the number of unrolls.
    name: the name of this operation (optional).
  Returns:
    A pair of Tensors, each shaped [batch_size, num_steps]. The second 
    element of the tuple is the same data time-shifted to the right by one.
  Raises:
    tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError: if batch_size or num_steps are too high.
  """
  with tf.name_scope(name, "PTBProducer", [raw_data, batch_size, num_steps]):
    raw_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(raw_data, name="raw_data", dtype=tf.int32)
    data_len = tf.size(raw_data)   # prints 929,589
    batch_len = data_len // batch_size   # prints 46,497
    data = tf.reshape(raw_data[0 : batch_size * batch_len],
                      [batch_size, batch_len])      
    #this truncates raw data to a multiple of batch_size=20, 
    #then reshapes to [20, 46497].  prints (20,?)

    epoch_size = (batch_len - 1) // num_steps   #prints 1327 (number of epoches)
    assertion = tf.assert_positive(
        epoch_size,
        message="epoch_size == 0, decrease batch_size or num_steps")
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
      epoch_size = tf.identity(epoch_size, name="epoch_size")

    i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()
    #for each of the 1327 epoches
    x = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps], [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps])   # prints (?, ?) 
    x.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])  #prints (20,35) 
    y = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps + 1], [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps + 1])
    y.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])
    return x, y
```

Comment: I think Oriol Vinyals wrote this code and wanted it to directly load the preprocessed penn tree bank files that Mikolov used. In my opinion, this method of loading the data is not easy to understand for Tensorflow beginners.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. where in the matrix is [0,1*35+1] and [20, (1+1)*35+1]? What spots in the (20, 46497) the begin and end in strided_slice is trying to access?

So the data matrix is arranged as `20 x 46497`. Think of it as 20 sentences with 46497 characters each. The strided slice in your specific example will get character 36 to 70 (71 is not included, typical range semantics) from each line. This is equivalent to

```py
strided = [data[i][36:71] for i in range(20)]
```

> 2. It seems like EVERY iteration of i, will take in data from 0? the very start of the data matrix (20, 46497)?

This is correct. For each iteration we want batch size elements in first dimension i.e. we want a matrix of size `batch size x num_steps`. Hence the first dimension always goes from 0-19, essentially looping over each sentence. And second dimension increments in `num_steps`, getting segments of words from each sentence. If we look at the index it extracts from data at each step for `x`, we will get something like:

```
- data[0:20,0:35]
- data[0:20,35:70]
- data[0:20,70:105]
- ...
```

For `y` we add 1 because we want next character to be predicted.
So your train, label tuples will be like:

```
- (data[0:20,0:35], data[0:20, 1:36])
- (data[0:20,35:70], data[0:20,36:71])
- (data[0:20,70:105], data[0:20,71:106])
- ...
```